# copy row values from one sheet to another sheet for the matched records in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in an excel workbook and Sheet1 has the following columns:

[image: Sheet1]

and Sheet 2 has only ID column:

[image: Sheet2]

If ID in sheet 2 matches with ID in sheet 1 I want to write col1 and col2 values in sheet1 to sheet 2

[image]

I used VLOOK up to identify the matched records but I am manually copying the values of the matched records into sheet 2 and I have to do this for 100,000 rows. I really appreciate if I can get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sheet 2, in cel `B2` write this formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0),2),"")`

In your sheet 2, in cel `C2` write this formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$C$4,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0),3),"")`

Change matrix offcourse to your needs and drag down!